# If $\left(3-x,\:x,\:\sqrt{9-x}\right)$ is an arithmetic sequence, find its sixth term.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To me it seems that this isn't an arithmetic sequence, because of the third term. I found that X is 5, but if that's the case the difference between the terms is not constant. How can I solve this?

Comment: "I found that X is 5" How????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that if $(3-x,x,\sqrt{9-x})$ is an arithmetic progression then

$$d=x-(3-x)=\sqrt{9-x}-x$$

Solve this equation to obtain $x=\frac{17}{9}$.

Finally, observe that $d=\frac{7}{9}$ and so $a_6=a_1+5d=3-x+5d=\frac{10}{9}+5\cdot\frac{7}{9}=5$

**Edit:**

From a comment below, if we allow the value of the square root to be the negative value we can obtain $x=0$ and $d=-3$ so $a_6=3+5(-3)=-12$

Comment: If the negative square root is allowed, x=0 also works.

Comment: It gives 3, 0, -3.

Comment: @martycohen Oh like that. I thought you meant in the computation.

Answer (score 0):

To be an arithmetic sequence,
we need
$x-(3-x)
= \sqrt{9-x}-x
$
or
$3x-3
=\sqrt{9-x}
$
or
$9x^2-18x+9 = 9-x
$
or
$9x^2-17x = 0$.

This gives
$x = 0$
or
$x = 17/9$.

For $x=0$,
this gives
$3, 0, \sqrt{9}$,
so we have to take the
negative square root.

For $x=17/9$,
this gives
$3-17/9 = 10/9,
17/9,
\sqrt{9-17/9}
=\sqrt{64/9}
=8/3
=24/9$
which works.

Now get the sixth term.

Answer (score 0):

To be an arithmetic sequence the differences in terms *must* be constant.

So $x - (3-x) = 2x -3$ *must* equal $\sqrt{9-x} - x$

So $\sqrt{9-x} - x$ *must* equal $2x -3$.

So... just solve that.... It's a straight forward quadratic.

"I found that $X$ is $5$".  I'm utterly perplexed as to *how* you found that.

"but if that's the case the difference between the terms is not constant" But keeping the difference constant is the *ONLY* criterion we know of for the value of $x$.  If $x =5$ doesn't keep the difference constant I utterly fail to see *how* on earth you could have derived $x = 5$ in the first place.

$\sqrt{9-x} - x = 2x - 3; x \le 9$

$\sqrt{9-x} = 3x -3 \ge 0; x\le 9$

$9-x = 9(x^2 - 2x +1); 1 \le x \le 9$.

$9x^2 - 17x = 0; 1\le x \le 9$

$9x =17; 1\le x \le 9$

$x = \frac {17}9$.

And that *is* a an arithmethic series.

$3 - x = \frac {10}9$ and $x = \frac {17}9$ and $\sqrt {9 -\frac{17}9}= \sqrt{\frac {94}9} = \frac 83$.

And the difference is constant:

$\frac {17}9 - \frac {10}9 = \frac 79$.  And $\frac 83 - \frac {17}9 = \frac 79$.

Not a problem.

But $x$ *must* be $\frac {17}9$.